# Is there a way to run a script on gimp startup?

Tags: gimp

Now that I know how to play with python fu, there are certain things I want gimp to do when started, in there a way to do this via python script?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do you could simply edit the `gimp.desktop` file in
 `/usr/share/applications`.
Just look up the `Exec=gimp-2.8 %U` value and change it to something like
`Exec=gimp-2.8 | python /path/to/your/script.py`.

Or you can put your script in one of the gimp plugins folders at `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/plug-ins` or `~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins`
 (obviously using replacing these version numbers with the appropriate ones for you).

This is probably the better way to go if you want to do gimp stuff with your script because it will be loaded properly when gimp starts.

Comment: This way (the second one), I'll have to click a menu item, right? Is there a way to keep this available without creating an image first?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a wrapper for `gimp` as follow:

- Get root privileges:

  ```
  sudo -i
  ```
- Move `gimp` file in another directory which is not in any user's PATH (for example `/opt`- don't forget where you move it):

  ```
  mv /usr/bin/gimp-2.8 /new/path/to/gimp-2.8
  ```
- Create your wrapper for `gimp` in `/usr/bin`:

  ```
  gedit /usr/bin/gimp-2.8
  ```

  Add the following script inside:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  #first run your executable script
  /path/to/your/script

  /new/path/to/gimp-2.8
  ```

  Save the file and close it.
- Make the new wrapper executable:

  ```
  chmod +x /usr/bin/gimp-2.8
  ```
- Logout from root session:

  ```
  exit
  ```

Next, when you will start `gimp`, `/path/to/your/script` will be run first.

Comment: I want the script to do something within gimp. My question wasn't clear enough probably.

Comment: Ok, this was a very simple example how you can do it. You can replace that wrapper script as you wish, even with your script if this in the end opens gimp.